# Ionic2 - Displaying project images on the UI

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the following brand new project, created with:

```
$ ionic start MyIonic2Project sidemenu --v2
```

[image]

My `question` is very simple:

- where do I locate a directory for `application images` (asset images / fixed images / icons / etc)?, inside: {resources, src, www, etc}?. I'm looking for `best practices`.
- how the url of these images would look like?. I wanna specify the `<img src="<url/to/image.jpg>" />` element within the file: `src/pages/home/home.ts`.

Comment: i think its better to keep inside`www\images` folder

Comment: then, not inside `src`?

Comment: no .its common to keep inside `www`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/assets/` folder should contain all the resources. You can use any sub-folder depending on type of resource. During the build process everything in the `src/assets` is copied to `www/assets`.

> how the url of these images would look like?

You have to give the path relative to your current file when it would be in www folder.
It is generally `../assets/../filename` if you are setting in your scss file.(This would end up as part of main.css within build folder).
and `./assets/../filename` in your html file.

Comment: I like this more. One other question, what about `css` files?, and common `css` files?

Comment: ionic 2 uses scss.. they all get transpiled and end up in main.css.. you can directly set css in scss..