# ionic app assets gone after deploying

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an app with ionic and have the following problem:

In my browser, everything looks like it should:

Browser view:

[image: Browser view]

But when I deploy everything like described under https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/ every asset looks like it's gone (fonts, images etc.):

Deployed view:

[image: Deployed view]

I also released the app for testing in test flight and had the same issue on an iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 6s and iPhone 6SE, all with the newest available iOS version.

I have my assets under /src/assets, not under /www/assets - so what's the problem there?

Comment: what path did you use to access the resources in your code?

Comment: @SurajRao As I said, I used the /src/assets path

Comment: no.. I meant the code (html/css) while accessing your assets e.g images.

Comment: @SurajRao I accessed it like this: url('../../assets/fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf');

Comment: your relative path is actually incorrect.https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626074/4826457

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: @SurajRao It works. Needed to do "ionic cordova prepare" before building. Thank you so much!